# No main manifest attribute, in gdx-setup.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, android-studio

Yesterday i found the gdx library and read a good tutorial, now i'm about to start, but when i launch:

```
java -jar gdx-setup.jar --dir "C:\Flappy\" --name "Flappy" --package xx.xxx.flappy --mainClass "MainGameActivity" --sdkLocation "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk"
```

it says:

no main manifest attribute, in gdx-setup.jar

and when i launch the ui setup:

```
Master config file
Version number

are highlighted red 0/?? (?%)
```

i was eager to start developing my game, but this errors arose... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using an old setup application. It was used on version 0.9.9 and is now outdated and unsupported . It still works though, even without the downloaded files, if you just start it, fill all input fields and select a downloaded libgdx version on your hard drive.

If you just started with libgdx, I'd suggest you to download version 1.0.0 [from here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/libgdx-1.0.0.zip). The "Latest stable version" link on the website still points to the old version.

This new setup will create gradle projects for you and gradle will handle the download of all necessary .jar files for you. See [this documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html#gettingstarted) to see how everything should be setup. You can read it in the wiki, or even watch videos about it. The links are all on this page.

Comment: Thaaaaaaank you sooooo much! I did download the archive from the official website, but it was the 0.9.9 i don't know why...

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted, so it won't be listed as unsolved anymore.

Comment: if you're already online, i was using a guide made for 0.9.9... is there anything different from that version to this? because i'm using the new one now and something seems to be different

Comment: Yes, the API has changed in a few places. The biggest change might be the introduction of `Viewport`, but in total it's not that much. If you have a specific question, you should probably open a new question, or just visit the #libgdx channel on IRC (freenode network). PS: the answer is still not *accepted*. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today. Contrary to the accepted answer, that is not the right solution.

The actual solution is that you're not building your project correctly. You need to run `gradle dist` to build the full JAR file, complete with manifest entry, for it to be a self-executing JAR.

You should always download the latest version of libGDX from their website. Here's a link to the [latest nightlies version](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup.jar) of libGDX.